# Regex to replace date and hour

Tags: javascript, regex, mask

can someone help me doing this mask, the part of date is ok but I don't know how to implement  the hour?
The regex is: `(\d{2}\/)+(\d{4})\s*(\d{2}:\d{2})/`

```
const onMask =  (v, mask) => {   
    if (!v) return;
    v = v.replace(/\D/g,'');
    switch(mask) {
        case 'datehour':
            v = v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, '$1/$2');
            v = v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, '$1/$2');
            v = v.replace(/(\d{4})(\d)/, '$1 $2');
            break;
    }
```

Comment: What's your input and expected output?

Comment: The answer already solves my problem, it'ok dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm, just to have all kind of masks is having the seconds too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like

```js
var v = '23-12-2021 12-34' 
v = v.replace(/\D+/g, ''); 
v = v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/, '$1/$2');
v = v.replace(/^(\d{2}\/\d{2})(\d)/, '$1/$2');
v = v.replace(/^(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})(\d)/, '$1 $2');
v = v.replace(/^(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2})(\d)/, '$1:$2');
console.log(v)
```

Remove non-numeric characters before re-formatting the data, add space/slash/colon in expected places.

Comment: Nothing less than perfect, I spent all my day trying to do that and nothing, just perfect. Just one more and if I need the seconds, how it was?

Comment: @LucianoCoelho It will be the same logic. Add `v = v.replace(/^(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2})(\d)/, '$1:$2');`